# Is there a way in vim to determine if something is highlighted after search?

Tags: search, autocmd, highlight

What I want to do is make `CursorMoved` autocmd that would check if there is a search highlight is on and if it is it would start a timer that would deactivate it.

PS
I know about all available workarounds like [this plugin](https://github.com/romainl/vim-cool) etc. They aren't good enough.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to test for search highlighting but maybe you could use `search()` with the content of `@/`: if the result is not zero, then the last search has a match in the buffer and you can then use `:nohl`. See [`:h search()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#search%28%29), [`:h @/`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%40%2F) (and [`:h setreg()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#setreg%28%29) to handle registers properly)

Comment: Well, this kind of useless, because I can just do `:nohl` in timer (I hope I can, because `:noh` by itself doesn't work in autocmd. Doing `:noh` should be less expensive than search I guess.

Comment: Yup you're totally right, that wasn't a clever idea :-)

Comment: The universal problem with `hlsearch` and `:nohlsearch` is precisely that they can't be used in functions or autocommands. This is what forces everyone to look for hacky workarounds. Also, keep in mind that timers didn't exist until very recently.

Comment: you mean like [this](https://gist.github.com/chrisbra/737b4b0487a7798af6f179bda9ce8c09#file-searchhighlight-vim)?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I haven't knew about feedkeys and still haven't figured out completely how it works, but it works, thanks!

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Okay, this isn't working properly, because for some reason sometimes I get part of your code inserted when using search as motion.

Comment: @user1685095 that is caused by the timer being triggered in the wrong mode. fixed that.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks. Not fully what I want (see my issue on github https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/5581), but answers the question!